# Best approach to designing DAL with ADO.NET for MVC 3 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, repository-pattern, data-access-layer

I see a ton of examples for MVC DAL with entity framework, but nothing for ADO.NET and stored procedures?
There seems to be a trend on the "Repository" pattern and "UnitofWork" for creating a DAL, similar to this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207820/The-Repository-Pattern-with-EF-code-first-Dependen

How would I migrate this codebase away from EF to ADO.net stored procedures?

Comment: Using stored procedures is dictated by our organization, we must use them. Need an idea to organize the DAL for the stored procs.

Comment: Show your manager this question. It's a really outdated strategy to force the usage of stored procedures.

Comment: Could you not create yet another layer of abstraction in order to create an implementation which uses ADO.NET.

Answer (score 7):

> How would I migrate this codebase away from EF to ADO.net stored procedures?

You have gotten very few answers as most of us are moving away from stored procedures.

The two biggest reasons for that are:

## Control over the business logic

Having all the business logic in one place makes it easier to read the code, and therefore maintain the application.  i.e. you get a muc better flow when programming.

If you spread out the business logic between SPs and .NET code you have to mentally shift (store state) each time to switch between code and SPs.

## Easier to test

Testing is important. Especially for applications which have a maintenance plan.

For .NET there are several tools for testing your code. Everything can be tested in isolation (without external dependencies) with little effort, and there are several articles describing different test techniques.

Testing stored procedures in isolation is hard.

---

## Myth: Stored procedures is faster than SQL queries.

Today stored procedures do not have a performance gain over parameterized queries (i.e. queries that uses arguments as `@userName`) as they did a couple of years ago (SQL Server 2000 and below). They should infact have similar performance as the execution plan is now saved for parameterized queries too.

However, if you have logic in your SP:s which process the result from multiple queries they DO get better performance as no roundtrip between your application and the database server is required. But the can easily be compensated by different application architecture.

## Conclusion

Think twice before going down that path. It's usually not worth it. What you gain (money) in less CPU cycles is typically a lot less than the amount of hours spent on creating and maintaining the application.

That said, stored procedures can be used as instructed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx